# SQL - Aggregate the common terms

Tags: sql, sql-server

I working on a SQL query to obtain the common terms in strings in multiple rows and merge it with '/', For example

```
ID ROW1  ROW2  FINAL_RESULT
1   A     A,B      A/B
2   A/B   A,C      A/B,C
3   A,B   A,C      A/B,C
```

I'm working on with the below query, but it didn't give me the result what I'm expecting

```
update table1
set  FINAL_RESULT = 
 case when ( CHARINDEX( ROW1  ,ROW2 ) > 0 ) then
                    ROW1  + '/' +Replace(ROW2  , ROW1  , '')
```

Comment: Your names are confusing, you call them `ROWx` when they're actually columns.

Comment: In line 1, `B` is not a common term, so I would guess it should not be part of the final result...

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a `CHARINDEX()` function. Are you sure that's the database you're using?

Comment: "*Common terms*" implies **intersection**. Your examples show **union**.  So what do you reaqlly need?

Comment: Does: (1) The delimiter between the terms in source values makes no sense and can be any (or it can be either comma or slash); (2) The format of final result is `(common terms as CSV) / (individual terms as CSV)`.

Comment: @Akina ,yes exactly that's what the final value should be.

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version? What is **complete** list of possible delimiters in source values? What is maximal terms amount per source value? Does duplicated value in single source value is possible (for example, `ROW1='A,A'`)?

Comment: @Akina, sorry for the confusion, It's Microsoft SQL Server  v18.8. comma and slash are the two possible delimiters , maximal terms amount per source value can be 4 and it does have duplicates ('A,A')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method uses a full join of string_splits.
To find what's common or uncommon between the columns.
Then glues them together.

> ```
> update t
> set final_result = CONCAT(ca.common, '/' + ca.uncommon)
> from table1 t
> outer apply (
>   select 
>    string_agg(common,',') as common, 
>    string_agg(uncommon,',') as uncommon
>   from (
>     select 
>       case when s1.value is null then s2.value
>            when s2.value is null then s1.value 
>       end as uncommon
>     , case when s1.value = s2.value then s1.value 
>       end as common
>     from      string_split(replace(col1,'/',','),',') s1
>     full join string_split(replace(col2,'/',','),',') s2
>       on s1.value = s2.value
>   ) q
> ) ca;
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from table1
> ```

| id | col1 | col2 | final_result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A,B | A/B |
| 2 | A/B | A,C | A/B,C |
| 3 | A,B | A,C | A/B,C |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4bbd31da6f0f0be0e6d11edafaef090e)*

Or add a UDF for the purpose.

> ```
> create function [dbo].[CombineCommonTerms]
> (
>     @Value1 varchar(100),
>     @Value2 varchar(100), 
>     @Delim char(1) = '/'
> )
> returns varchar(200)
> as 
> begin
>     declare @tbl1 table (col varchar(30));
>     declare @tbl2 table (col varchar(30));
>     
>     set @Value1 = replace(@Value1,@Delim,',');
>     declare @Xml1 xml = cast('<d>'+ replace(@Value1,',','</d><d>') +'</d>' as xml);
>     
>     set @Value2 = replace(@Value2,@Delim,',');
>     declare @Xml2 xml = cast('<d>'+ replace(@Value2,',','</d><d>') +'</d>' as xml);
>     
>     insert into @tbl1 (col)
>     select  distinct ltrim(rtrim(a.split.value('.', 'varchar(30)') )) as col
>     from    @Xml1.nodes('/d') a(split);
>     
>     insert into @tbl2 (col)
>     select distinct ltrim(rtrim(a.split.value('.', 'varchar(30)'))) as col
>     from    @Xml2.nodes('/d') a(split);
>     
>     declare @Common varchar(100);
>     select @Common = concat(@Common+',', t1.col)
>     from @tbl1 t1 
>     inner join @tbl2 t2 
>       on t2.col = t1.col;
>     
>     declare @Uncommon varchar(100);
>     select @Uncommon = concat(@Uncommon+',', coalesce(t1.col, t2.col))
>     from @tbl1 t1 
>     full join @tbl2 t2 
>       on t2.col = t1.col
>     where (t1.col is null or t2.col is null);
>     
>     return concat(@Common, @Delim + @Uncommon);
> end;
> ```

> ```
> update t
> set final_result = [dbo].[CombineCommonTerms](col1, col2, default)
> from table1 t;
>
> select *
> from table1;
> ```

| id | col1 | col2 | final_result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A,B | A/B |
| 2 | A/B | A,C | A/B,C |
| 3 | A,B | A,C | A/B,C |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=aa499bd21a640554165f3242b5cfdc2b)*

Comment: Thanks, that works. but string_split is not allowed to use

Comment: @Maddy I've added a function for it.